# Search and replace multiple lines from a file

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to remove a part of `a.txt` file and replace with contents of `b.txt` file while also doing modification to other lines in `a.txt` using a Perl program.

**file a.txt**

```
line1
line2 
replace from below line
replace from this line
bla bla...
bla bla...
to this line
line3
line4
```

**file b.txt**

```
replacement1
replacement2
replacementn
```

Below is my code which is not working.

```
#!/apps/perl/5.8.3/bin/perl -w
   open (INPUT, "a.txt")              or die $!;
   open (REPLACE, "b.txt")            or die $!;
   open (OUTPUT, ">c.txt")          or die $!;

my $replace_text;
{
    local $/;
    $replace_text = <REPLACE>;
}
close(REPLACE);

while (<INPUT>) {
   s/line1/modified_line1/;
   s/line2/modified_line2/;
   
   if($_ =~ /replace from below line/){
       while(<INPUT>){
             {
                local undef $/;
                s/replace from this line.*to this line/$replace_text/smg;
             }
       s/line3/modified_line3/;
       s/line4/modified_line4/;
       print OUTPUT;
   }
}
}
close(INPUT);
close(OUTPUT);
```

**Expected output file c.txt**

```
modified_line1
modified_line2
replacement1
replacement2
replacementn
modified_line3
modified_line4
```

Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `open (INPUT, "filename")` has been bad practice for many years.  Don't use raw file handle names.  `open my $f, mode, name` is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I like perl, it's really not necessary here:

```
sed -e 's/line1/modified_line1/' \
    -e 's/line2/modified_line2/' \
    -e 's/line3/modified_line3/' \
    -e 's/line4/modified_line4/' \
    -e '/replace from below/rb.txt' \
    -e '/replace from below/,/to this line/d' a.txt
modified_line1
modified_line2
replacement1
replacement2
replacementn
modified_line3
modified_line4
```

If you did want to use perl, I'd just do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $ah, '<', "a.txt" or die "a.txt: $!\n";

while(<$ah>) {
        s/line1/modified_line1/;
        s/line2/modified_line2/;
        s/line3/modified_line3/;
        s/line4/modified_line4/;
        if( /replace from below/ ){
                system "cat b.txt" and exit 1;
        }
        next if( /replace from below/ .. /to this line/);
        print;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need nested `while` loops to read your input file.

One way is to use a variable to control when you print to the output file:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (INPUT, "a.txt")   or die $!;
open (REPLACE, "b.txt") or die $!;
open (OUTPUT, ">c.txt") or die $!;

my $replace_text;
{
    local $/;
    $replace_text = <REPLACE>;
}
close(REPLACE);

my $print = 1;
while (<INPUT>) {
    s/line(\d)/modified_line$1/;
    $print = 0 if /replace from below line/;
    if (/to this line/) {
        $print = 1;
        $_ = $replace_text;
    }
    print OUTPUT if $print;
}
close(INPUT);
close(OUTPUT);
```

Output:

```
modified_line1
modified_line2 
replacement1
replacement2
replacementn
modified_line3
modified_line4
```

I also consolidated your 4 `line` substitutions into 1 using `\d`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem description does not specify how big can be `a.txt` file. Posted code utilizes regular expression with modifier `/smg` what indicates that OP tries to work on multiline text.

Let's assume that input file is small enough to be read and processed in the memory.

For code manageability substitute placed into `__DATA__` block which read in `%substitute` hash.

Build regular expression `$re` based on `keys %substitute` to utilize in substitution pattern.

Multiline substitution is based on original OP's code (is not applicable to line by line read of input data).

Two subroutines defined to read content of the file into variable and to store variable data into a file -- just to make the code easier to read and understand.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($fname_in,$fname_repl,$fname_out) = qw/a.txt b.txt c.txt/;

my %substitute = split(/[,\s]/, do{ local $/; <DATA>} );
my $re = '\b(' . join('|',keys %substitute) . ')\b';

my $data = read_file($fname_in);
my $replace_with = read_file($fname_repl);

$data =~ s/$re/$substitute{$1}/g;
$data =~ s/replace from below line.*?to this line/$replace_with/gsm;

save_file($fname_out,$data);
say $data;

exit 0;

sub read_file {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $data;
    
    open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Couldn't open $fname";
    $data = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close $fh;
    
    return $data;
}

sub save_file {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $data  = shift;
    
    open my $fh, '>', $fname
        or die "Couldn't open $fname";
    say $fh $data;
    close $fh;
}

__DATA__
line1,modified_line1
line2,modified_line2
line3,modified_line3
line4,modified_line4
```

Output

```
modified_line1
modified_line2
replacement1
replacement2
replacementn
modified_line3
modified_line4
```